# Replace 'right' with 'left' and 'left' with 'right' in a file

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I have a file called `bootstrap.css.scss`. I want to add Right to Left support for it. In order to do so I need to replace all the occurrences of the string `'right'` with `'left'` and all the occurrences of the string `'left'` with `'right'` in that file. How can I do that in ruby?

Comment: I assume that you would want words like `righteous` and `cleft` to be left (LEFT!) alone, right? (RIGHT?)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker no, I need to replace them too.

Comment: Ignoring the possibility that right and left might be substrings of another string you don't want changed, you could just replace `right` to a unique string like `TEMP`, replace `left` with `right`, then replace `TEMP` with `left`...

Comment: I need to replace the strings like `pull-right` and `pull-left` too. not the strings like `righteous` and `cleft`

Comment: So Sajjad, you just changed your mind in the last 6 minutes?  How about editing the question with some example inputs and outputs to clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: @David Grayson I was not sure that there is such a string in that file. I just saw the file, There is no string like 'righteous' in it. So it doesn't matter and I don't need to edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct your replacement text on the fly:

```
result = subject.gsub(/right|left/) {|match|
    match == "left" ? "right" : "left"
}
```

This matches `right` or `left`. Then, if the match turns out to be `left`, the replacement text is set as `right`, otherwise, it's set as `right`. Right?

You might want to use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) as in `/\b(?:right|left)\b/` instead if you only want to match entire words as in `pull-right`, and not `righteous`.

Comment: A similar option would be to use the version of `gsub` that accepts a hash: `gsub(/left|right/, 'left' => 'right', 'right' => 'left')`.

Comment: @matt: That's even cooler - you should write that as an answer.